# How to send an array using GET request from a input form in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm retrieving data from the database and I am using GET request to send the data to a page to delete the data. Now, I want to send an array which contains multiple tr's to delete the data and I want to do this using GET request, not POST request.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: i think for get request you add params to url

Comment: You can't send elements. Need to send some identifier from those elements. Show us a sample of html and also show us what you have tried

Comment: What did you try so far and what are the problems you're facing??

Comment: Please describe your issue what you encounter. You could send data by json string.

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad and unclear. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the arguments with ',' and use the code below to get a array.

```
$id_string = $_GET['id'];
$id_array = explode(',', $id_string);
```

Comment: Did you mean `explode` ?

Comment: PHP funtion,   id: 1,5,4   change   [0=>1,1=>5,2=>4]

Comment: You had a typo `expload`

Comment: PHP funtion    explode

Answer (score 0):

Convert form inputs into an array `info[item1], info[item2], info[item3]..`

Example:

```
 <form action="process.php" method="GET">
        input 1<br>
        <input type="text" name="info[item1]"><br>
        input 2<br>
        <input type="text" name="info[item2]"><br>
        input 3<br>
        <input type="text" name="info[item3]"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Get form inputs in PHP:

```
<?php

//Do not use $_GET to access superglobal $_GET Array Directly.
//Use filter_input_array() function.

$request = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET);

//Get form inputs of array 'info'
$input = $request['info'];

//Get form input value
foreach ($input as $key=>$value) 
{
   echo "<p>{$key}=>{$value}</p>";  
}
```

Output:

```
item1=> 1   // Input value to delete.

item2=> 2   // Input value to delete.

item3=>3    // Input value to delete.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that you have data in form of the array $data

```
<?php
```

$data= array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

?>

```
<form action="test.php" method="GET">


   <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php print base64_encode(serialize($data)); ?>"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">



</form>
```

After form submition it will create a url with querystring having coded value of you array.
We can get that value on test.php page and use that to delete rows according to your data(getting from URL).

```
<?php

$str_var = $_GET["data"];
$array_var = unserialize(base64_decode($str_var));
foreach($array_var as $id)

{

echo $id;


$server=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$re=mysqli_query($server,"DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id=$id");

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass your data ids as string with commas separated like:

https://your.url.here/?ids=1,3,5,7,8

and server splits the commas to retrieve values.

For example:

```js
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?ids=1,2,3,4,5"; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
console.log(url.searchParams.get("ids").split(','));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Whoever downvoted, why wouldn't this solution work (granted the user knows how to delete data from a database and possible basic usage of for loop)?